# Post image to Particular Channel

Tags: iphone, mobli

i am using your api and i have made a success call to upload a photo to my profile.
now i am trying to post to Particular channel, what is the value i need to put for channel id....
tried this values :
"/channel/{channel_id}"
"channel_id"
"channel"

```
    NSString *mediaCaption = [self.uploadedMediaInfo valueForKey:@"text"];
UIImage *img = viewImage;//[self.uploadedMediaInfo valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

NSMutableDictionary *uploadMediaParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          @"jpg",                       @"extension",
                                          /*@"215913",                   @"/channel/{channel_id}",*/
                                          /*mediaCaption,                 @"text",*/
                                          nil];

// Additional parameters relevant to image upload are also added in the postImage request method
[self postImage:img params:uploadMediaParams delegate:self];
[self.uploadedMediaInfo removeAllObjects];
```

http://developers.mobli.com/documentation/authentication

Comment: Sorry but who's API are you talking about?

Comment: About mobli api it's kind a new but its awesome!

Comment: Then post links, background information about the API. Saying thing like: **i am using your api** isn't telling us much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use channels_list[] : An array of mobli channel id's